# Slack does not render properly a suer by userID through workflow

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

1. Save a userID in a google sheet doc.
2. Try to push a message in a chat with the userID (read from the doc) but instead of normal `@AdamLol` I see `<@USERID123>`.
   Can I somehow see the real name?

Answer (score 0):

Since at-handles can change, it's not recommended to rely on them. As such, you have three options in terms of output.

- Name
- Mention (user ID)
- Email

[image: Spreadsheet output from Workflow Builder]

You can pick between these options by choosing from the dropdown beside the variable

[image: Workflow Builder configuration for example above]

Comment: Hi, yes, you are right. But name or email will not trigger a notification for the user.